# Date Function Call Not Working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to call the constructor to call the checkDate function but no avail :(
..I'm really new to this.

```
class Date
{    
    public:
        Date();
    Date(int, int, int);
private:
    void checkDate(void);
    int month, day, year; 
};

Date:: Date() // default constructor
{
    month = 1;
day = 1;
year = 1960;
}

Date:: Date(int m, int d, int y) // constructor definition
{
m = month, d = day, y = year;
checkDate();
}

void Date:: checkDate() // function to check date
{
if (month < 1 || month > 12)
    exit(0);
else if (day < 1 || day > 31)
    exit(0);
else if (year < 1960 || year > 2013)
    exit(0);
else
    cout << "Works." << endl;
}

int main()
{
Date();
Date(1, 1, 1960); //make this work PLEASEEEEEE <333333333333333333333
}
```

This is what I have so far.
I'm new to this site, not sure if I posted correctly.

Comment: I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get a better idea of how to debug this. Quite honestly, one line in particular is perfect for the rubber duck technique.

Comment: I would also recommend fixing your indentation.

Comment: FYI, the `exit` function exits the program, which may also exit the function.  I don't think this is what you want.  Look up the `return` statement.  If you are going to exit the program because of error, please output a description of the cause before the program exits.

Comment: oh um i only used the exit function because the prof told us to lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you date(int ,int,int) constructor is assigning the variables incorrectly. What you want is month = m; day =d; year = y;

Comment: HEYY YOU FIXED IT <333333333

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Date:: Date(int m, int d, int y) // constructor definition
{
    m = month, d = day, y = year;
    checkDate();
}
```

To

```
Date:: Date(int m, int d, int y) // constructor definition
{
    month = m, day = d, year = y ;
    checkDate();
}
```

I would actually change aaaalot, but this is the simplest answer I can give you besides, work, work, work.